# What's the real range of pitch and roll return by SensorManager.getOrientation?

Tags: android, sensormanager

[The android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) says:

[image: android doc]

But I test on my android device, the range of pitch is -π/2 to π/2, the range of roll is -π to π.
And then I check the source code of [SensorManager.getOrientation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java#1491), I find the pitch is calculated by Math.asin and roll is Math.atan2:
[image: the source code of SensorManager.getOrientation]

As we know, the range return by Math.asin is **-π/2 to π/2** and the range return by Math.atan2 is **-π to π**, so this is contradict [the android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)).

Comment: Thanks @greeble31, I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: Any idea how to get the pitch from 0 to 2 π?